# Find All Files With Parentheses?

Tags: powershell

I recently got a new laptop and for some reason DropBox decided to duplicate everything in there.  I like to teach myself a bit of PoSH a often as I can so I can be more adept at it, so I figured this might be a good time, but so far, no luck with my mucking about.  I'm not a total noob, but definitely still a bit of one.

Basically all the dupe files have a (1) at the end (e.g. filename (1).txt). I was able to pinpoint those with:

```
gci -recurse | ? { $_.Name -like "*(1)*" }
```

Good so far, but then I want to move them to a "dupes" directory and keep the subfolder structure.  For whatever reason, what seems like it should be simple, PoSH makes super hard.  I've searched high and low and found a few close examples, but they also include a bunch of other parameters that just end up confusing me.  What I believe I'm after is:

*Find items with the above command
*Pipe to Move-Item
*Somehow include New-Item -itemtype Directory -force 
*Also check to see that that dir doesn't already exist

Currently I have:

```
$from = "C:\users\xxx\Dropbox"
$to = "C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\DropBox Dupes"
gci | ? { $_.Name -like "*(1)*" } | New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $to -Force
Move-Item $from $to -Force
```

Any pointers/help/examples?

Thanks!

P.s. Though I've stopped dropbox and tried a few different files, I'm currently getting:

```
Move-Item : Cannot move item because the item at 'C:\users\jkelly.MC\Dropbox' is in use.
At line:2 char:1
+ Move-Item $from $to -Force
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Move-Item],     PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MoveItemCommand
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
$source = "C:\Dropbox"
$destination = "C:\DropboxDupes"
gci .\Dropbox -Recurse -File | ?{ $_.basename -match ".*\(\d+\)$"} | % {

    $destination_filename = $_.fullname.Replace($source, $destination)
    $destination_dir = split-path $destination_filename -Parent
    if(-not (Test-Path $destination_dir -PathType Container)) {
        mkdir $destination_dir | out-null
    }
    move-item $_.fullname $destination_filename
}
```

It basically replaces the source base path with the destination base path in the files to preserve directory structure. You can fine tune it for your needs

Comment: Just seeing this now, thanks, will check it out.  Never been very adept at regex, but guess I need to hunker down and learn - keep seeing it in various examples of PoSH stuff I"m trying to do.