# Move files with folders

Tags: regex, powershell

My Google Drive for an unknown reason creates multiple duplicates of certain files in a format of: filename (2021_02_08 11_22_39 UTC).ext

I would like to move these files on another folder, just in case.
I found this thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18164803/find-all-files-with-parentheses) which seems similar.
Im not quite an expert on regex. Could you please help me out on that?

Regex: [a-zA-Z]+). for searching: UTC).

I suppose it should read something like:

```
$source = "C:\Dropbox"
$destination = "C:\DropboxDupes"
gci .\Dropbox -Recurse -File | ?{ $_.basename -match "[a-zA-Z]+\)\."} | % {

    $destination_filename = $_.fullname.Replace($source, $destination)
    $destination_dir = split-path $destination_filename -Parent
    if(-not (Test-Path $destination_dir -PathType Container)) {
        mkdir $destination_dir | out-null
    }
    move-item $_.fullname $destination_filename
}
```

Comment: You can also add `-Filter '????_??_?? ??_??_?? UTC.ext'` to your search to make it even faster.

Comment: This answer from eight (8) years ago looks familiar. https://stackoverflow.com/a/18165832/447901

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `'\([\d_\s]+UTC\)'` to match digits, underscore, and space followed by 'UTC' and all enclosed in parentheses.

It is best practice for script writing not to use aliases, use parameter names, and stick with case.

```
$source = "C:\Dropbox"
$destination = "C:\DropboxDupes"
Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Recurse -File |
    Where-Object { $_.BaseName -match '\([\d_\s]+UTC\)'} |
    ForEach-Object {
        $destination_filename = $_.FullName.Replace($source, $destination)
        $destination_dir = Split-Path -Path $destination_filename -Parent
        if (-not (Test-Path -Path $destination_dir -PathType Container)) {
            New-Item -Type Directory -Path $destination_dir | Out-Null
        }
        Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $destination_filename
    }
```